# I have an emergency. Lost Android

Tags: lost-phone

We have lost an Android phone. Every possible aspect that could make it more difficult has happened to be an encouragement to surrender.
We do not have the IMEI, it does not have access to internet that we know of (Unless the thief connects it to Wi-Fi), and so on. I was wondering if there is a way to locate the phone via Cellular Towers. I know a tower CAN locate a phone using just its connection strength. Maybe that's a good solution??? Any help is appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to locate your device:

1. If your phones gets some cellular data, try going to *Android Device Manager* and remotely wipe it to make sure that nothing is traced.
2. **File** a police report. Sometimes, it can communicate between nearby towers and get some signal nearby. Tell them that you lost your phone and may suspect that your phone is taken already.

Hope this helps. It will give some helpful ideas when you lose a phone.